# How to execute something after an error in R/Shiny?

Tags: r, resources, shiny, disconnect

I wanted to know if there is a way to execute something after an error ocurred.

I am currently working with some databases and I need to liberate resources after an error, with a statement like `dbDisconnect(database)`

Thank you

Comment: U can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `tryCatch` with the `finally` block

```
tryCatch({
  # some code that initializes database
  # some code that runs a query
}, finally = dbDisconnect(database) )
```

The expression inside `finally` gets run regardless of whether the code in the try block was successful or threw an error.